# Drupal8: how to fix the error on trusted host setting?

Tags: drupal-8

I have error in configuration using Drupal8 as below:

TRUSTED HOST SETTINGS
Not enabled
The trusted_host_patterns setting is not configured in settings.php. This can lead to security vulnerabilities. It is highly recommended that you configure this.

I’ve fixed this error locally put code on local setting.php:

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
   '^drupal-8-2-6.dd$',
    '^localhost',
  );

But I could not fix this error on  hosting setting.php even so I’ve tried different attempts  as below
(assuming that sf- my domain and dr31 –is side, 
so internet access is www.dr31.sf.com):

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www.dr31.sf.com$',
);

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www.dr31.sf.com$',
);

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www.sf.com$',
);

Is it possible that some hosting settings prevent to make effect of its setting.php and as the result it creates the trusted hosts error?

For ex. permission on setting php.not 644 but 444 and even I've changed it on 644 in come back to 444.

I, personally don't think that this has any affect on trusted host error.
But why could not I get rid from error on hosting if I followed the same pattern as on local host where is no error?

How to fix the error of trusted host setting?

Thanks.

I've tried to change as suggested(see below) but it doesn't fix error:

Answer (score 3):

For drupal 9

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
'^localhost$',                              
'^192\.168\.00\.52$',
'^127\.0\.0\.1$',
];
```

I move the code end of the *settings.php* file, it work's fine,it might suitable for all drupal versions

because so much of comment blocks (comment block start with /**, end with */) are there in the *settings.php* file.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested pattern as below didn't clear up error in trusted host:

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(

'^www.dr31.sf.com$',

);

I've tried different combinations and eventually I find the solution  that helps to get rid of trusted hosts errors.

The code that I've used doesn't exactly follow those that provided in setting.php but it clear error in trusted hosts.

I've used the code as below to clear the error in trusted hosts:

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(

'^dr31.sf.com$',
);

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 comes with a default (example) settings file that can be really useful to consult when you're stuck on things like this.

This example settings file should be located in the following location:

`sites/default/default.settings.php`

This file is generally very well commented, and useful when trying to figure out problems like this.

If you look specifically at the trusted host patterns example, it gives this as an example if you only want your site to be accessible by www.example.com:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www\.example\.com$',
);
```

This differs slightly from the code you said you're using (which was `^www.dr31.sf.com$`), as the URL is formatted via a regular expression, you need to escape the periods using a backslash.

However, you might want your site to be accessible on www.example.com, and also example.com (or some other subdomains for example). If this is the case, you'll need to specify multiple URLs like this:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^example\.com$',
  '^.+\.example\.com$',
);
```

**Judging by what you've said, I would assume the following configuration would fix this for you:**

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www\.dr31\.sf\.com$',
);
```

You could also get away with much more lenient checks here, but I think the above is the most appropriate (as it doesn't sound like you're using Drupal to provide data on any other URLs/sub domains).

The permissions being changed is unrelated to your problem - as far as I understand, Drupal automatically resets these permissions to quite a restrictive setting to try and ensure your site is secure.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i've tried as you suggested but it doesn't fix error...What is surprised me that I put the host that doesn't exist like dr88888/sf9999 - and it still display page instead of message "The provided host name is not valid for this server."   
Could be something in php setting/anything else that prevent me to change hosts  regardless right or wrong/how to check it?

Comment: What precisely is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Take a look on my initial post line 2 to 5 - this is exact error on Report-Status Report

Comment: Are you sure that you're editing the correct settings file @Tatyana ? The default is located at: `sites/default/settings.php` but it may be possible that your site is setup to use a settings file located elsewhere. It might also be possible that the `trusted_host_patterns` array is overwritten as null further down the settings file. Unfortunately it's hard to know without access to the settings file and/or environment (which is a really bad idea for security reasons)

Comment: I have setting file  under sites/default. I've checked setting.php and there is under database setting, name of host is different. I've changed to this name - but the error doesn't disappeared..... It is like no reaction... Besides, this drupal side is very slow compare with for. ex google. Do Drupal slow?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was installing drupal 10 today and encountered the same error which won't go away even after updating the settings.php file. After pulling hair for some time, figured that the comment sections needs to be closed and then opened properly after uncommenting the trusted_host_patterns settings section and this was causing the problem **(ie, just uncommenting the section is not enough!)**.

```
 * @code
 */ <<-- THIS

 $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
    '^www\.example\.com$',
  ];

 /** <<-- THIS
 * @endcode
 * will allow the site to only run from www.example.com.
```

I know this is a very old post, but may help someone who is in the same situation.

Cheers!